# Is "I pray it rains today" proper English?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is a sentence that is always used and I would like to verify whether it is the proper usage. Is "I pray it rains today" a proper usage?

Comment: Hi Linda, what about the sentence makes you feel that it might not be correct? Is it because it seems like it's missing a word between "I pray" and "it rains"? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

If a sentence is often-used, it's probably not incorrect. If the sentence sounds grammatically awkward, then it may be idiomatic.

As for this particular sentence, I looked up "I pray it rains" on Google, and Google was only able to return 40 hits (and the first 3 were linked to this question). So I'm not sure who "always" uses this phrase.

Even though I think "I pray for rain" sounds a little more natural than "I pray it rains" (and the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20pray%20for%2CI%20pray%20it&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) would support this assertion), I still wouldn't deem this an "improper" usage. After all, there's nothing wrong with saying:

> I hope it rains.

And I can't see any reason why we can't use "I pray" in lieu of "I hope".

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't sound right or natural to me. Alternatives that come to my mind:

> I pray that it rains today

Or even simpler:

> I pray for rain today

or

> I'm praying for rain today

Comment: It's perfectly right and natural to countless native English speakers.